# What is the dual space of a von Neumann algebra?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

What is the dual space of a von Neumann algebra $\mathcal{M}$? Does it have any specific form? Or just $\mathcal{M}^*$.

Comment: What would "form" be? What kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: @MartinArgerami  Well, the predual of $\mathcal{M}$ is $\mathcal{L}_1(\mathcal{M},\tau)$. Something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already $\mathscr{B}(H)^*$ or even $L_\infty^*$ are intractable. However, $\mathscr{M}^{**}$ is a von Neumann algebra too, so $\mathscr{M}^*$ is indeed a predual of the second dual. This is the best we can say in that generality. Maybe you should rethink your question.

Comment: THX a lot, it is useful!